# Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[]

Tags: chainlink

I'm trying to generate a random number within a range using Chainlink, I keep getting - Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[]

I'm using the boilerplate from [Get a random number](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/examples/get-a-random-number/#analyzing-the-contract)

I modified it a bit to get one random word,

```
function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 /*requestId*/, uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override{
    s_randomWords = (randomWords[0] % 50) + 1;
}
```

so I noticed s_randomWords prompts this error Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[]

Comment: could you post more/all of your code pls? please show the code where you call the function. inferring from the error msg, it looks like you're passing in a single uint for the 2nd arg instead of an array of uint (even if the array is to have only one element)

Comment: Sure, I've edited it

Comment: where does it show how you are calling the function. the most important thing is to see the parameters you are trying to pass in as that what the error message is complaining about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be trying to assign a `uint256` to the `s_randomWords` variable which is of type `uint256[]` in the example.

```js
uint256[] public s_randomWords;
```

Better create a new state variable like:

```js
uint256 public s_randomWord;` // Notice now it's not plural, but singular.
```

And then using it in the `fulfillRandomWords` function:

```js
  function fulfillRandomWords(uint256, /* requestId */ uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override {
    s_randomWord = (randomWords[0] % 50) + 1;
  }
```

Comment: Perfect! it works now